# Post angularjs form to nodejs Express ( Bad request)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, post, express, request

im new in angularJs,  im trying to make a basic login with angularJS and nodejs ( server side), i dont care about security for now im just trying to learn how to post. so i made a login form and a controller with angular :

My Login Form :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
      <h1>Login</h2>
      <form class="form" >
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Username</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control"   ng-model="login.mail" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control"    ng-model="login.password" required>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="text" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

then my router & controller Angularjs :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('login', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
    });
}])

.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.login = function() {

            $http.post('/api/users/login', $scope.login).success(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
//                refresh();
            });
        };

}]);
```

and Server side i have that :

```
router.post('/login/', function(req, res) {

// here "/login/" means  "/users/login" ( in index of controllers)

    console.log(req.body.mail);

var usermail = req.body.mail;
var pass = req.body.password;
console.log(usermail + pass);



User.find({mail: usermail}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            console.log("ça marche pas")


        } else {

            res.json( user );
            console.log(user);
        }
    })


});
```

server side : it works ( when i use DHC chrome extension to Post) but when im using angularjs view i got that error :

**POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/login 400 (Bad Request)**

Please help me to solve that, i think i missed something. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are sending your login function as in below line:

```
$http.post('/api/users/login', $scope.login)
```

You probably want to pass a parameter in your login function that can be sent to server as below:

```
$scope.login = function(loginData) {

    $http.post('/api/users/login', loginData).success(function (response)
```

**Update**

You are assigning your form values to $scope.login. If you would create a separate variable for it, for example loginForm, you can send this as valid JSON to your API:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h1>Login</h2>
  <form class="form" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control"   ng-model="loginForm.mail" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control"    ng-model="loginData.password" required>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="text" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="login(loginData)">Login</button>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And .js:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.loginForm = {
           mail: '',
           password: ''
        };

        $scope.login = function(loginData) {
            // Check what this prints out:
            console.log(loginData);
            $http.post('/api/users/login', loginData).success(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
//                refresh();
            });
        };

}]);
```

Comment: i just want to send to the email and password figured in login form to my server   , im sure my controller is not working : now i tried with your expression it give me a 404 error

i forget to tell you that before i got bad request 400 , and in server side : invalid json

Comment: You will have to debug yourself what is being send to the server. If you use your browsers Developer Tools (F12). You can watch what is being send to your API. You can then check if the JSON you are sending is valid (on this website for example: http://json.parser.online.fr/).

Comment: I've updated my answer which shows how you can improve your code. You have a function $scope.login which you assign your variables to.

Comment: Thank you its working perfectly :) , thank you so much too from my collegue ( we are too ), now i understand my mistakes. 

Best regards 

Thank you

sorry i cant answer my question to tell you thank you so i do it here